# unrecognized escape sequence in a UNC with a varible

Tags: c#, powershell

The following code gives me the **unrecognized escape sequence** error at the two backslash for: `\C$\temp` in the code.

I tried with double `\\` and `""` but still doesn't work.

The code `+ txtWSName.Text +` is for a variable that will be the computer name.

```cs
txtFileDetails.Text = RunScript(@"Get-ChildItem \\ " + txtWSName.Text + " \C$\temp | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending");
```

What I am trying to do is navigate to the directory and view the files.

Comment: Either `@" \C$\temp ..."` or `" \\C$\\temp ..." *will* work in terms of the C# compiler. What they'll do with Powershell is a different matter. It's not clear what problem you saw when you tried using `\\`.

Comment: First generate the string you want to execute *then* execute it. The way the code is written makes it impossible to detect escaping errors. BTW `@"Get-ChildItem \\ "` in C# generates the string `Get-ChildItem \\ `. You have a whitespace after the slashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> C# supports two forms of string literals: regular string literals and verbatim string literals.
>
> A regular string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes, as in "hello", and may include both simple escape sequences (such as \t for the tab character) and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences.
>
> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A verbatim string literal may span multiple lines.

You want literal backslashes in your string literals. That means you must either escape them, or prepend the string with an `@` character (like you do with your first literal):

```cs
@"Get-ChildItem \\ " + txtWSName.Text + @" \C$\temp ..."
```

or

```cs
"Get-ChildItem \\\\ " + txtWSName.Text + " \\C$\\temp ..."
```

On top of that you need to remove the trailing space from the first string literal, and the leading space from the second one, otherwise you'll end up with an invalid path.

Bottom line, change this:

```cs
txtFileDetails.Text = RunScript(@"Get-ChildItem \\" + txtWSName.Text + " \C$\temp | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending");
```

into this:

```cs
txtFileDetails.Text = RunScript(@"Get-ChildItem \\" + txtWSName.Text + @"\C$\temp | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending");
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar for the explanation/documentation and the solution. I will have to read more on this. Its now working!

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in `@"Get-ChildItem \\ "` which means that `\\` is treated as a separate argument. You have another space in `" \C$\temp"`, which by the way, treats `\` as an escape character.

In general you should construct the string you want to execute in a *separate* line, to make debugging easier. The same goes for the execution results. Performance isn't going to be affected.

You should try:

```
var path   = @"\\" + txtWSName.Text + @"\C$\temp";
var script = "Get-ChildItem " + path + 
           " | sort-Object -property LastWriteTime -Descending";
var result = RunScript(script);
txtFileDetails.Text = result;
```

In C# 6 you could use string interpolation, to make the code cleaner and avoid generating temporary strings eg:

```
var server = txtWSName.Text;

var path   = $@"\\{server}\C$\temp";
var script = $"Get-ChildItem {path} | sort-Object -property LastWriteTime -Descending";
```